# Private react-native library all of a sudden can't be found even though I see it in the node_modules

Tags: react-native, github, npm

I have a react-native project that is using a private react-native library. Everything was working fine earlier, but now I am getting the error `Cannot find module 'library' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)`.

If I use a package from earlier in the day, everything works fine. I compared the code, and there were only 3 changes. I removed all of those changes and I am still having the same issue. I see the library in node_modules. It has an index.d.ts file as well as an index.ts file. I have no idea what is wrong, and I am basically stuck at the previous version because any changes I make or trying to revert the code back to this previous package all have the same results as above. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, no idea how this happened. The only thing that changed was that I updated VSCode, but my dist folder no longer had the src folder within it, so my paths were off, I guess. Made sure to export to dist/src in my tsconfig, and this worked to solve the issue, in case anyone else runs into this.